# Unintuitive output given by classes in Python

Tags: python

So I've got this class:

```
class Student(object):
    def __init__(self, studentID, name):
        self.__studentID = studentID
        self.__name = name

    def set_studentID(self, value):
        self.__studentID = value

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name
```

and running this code:

```
x = Student
x.set_name(x, input("Name: "))
x.set_studentID(x, len(students))
students.append(copy.deepcopy(x))
x.set_name(x, input("Name: "))
x.set_studentID(x, len(students))
students.append(copy.deepcopy(x))
for i in (students):
    print(i.get_name(i))
```

gives an unexpected output:

```
For the input:
a
b

the output is:
b
b

The expected output is:
a
b
```

If you answer please give me a short explanation of why it doesn't work

Comment: By the way, a single `_` is enough to declare a private property.

Comment: Don't use double-underscores unless you understand what they are for and you actually need them.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code isn't working is because you **never instantiate your class**, instead, you assign the class object itself to the name `x`

```
x = Student
```

When you really needed

```
x = Student()
```

Then you call the methods on the class object, whilst passing the class object itself as the first parameter, thus your getters and setters act on the class object.

Finally, classes are meant to be singletons, and the `copy` module special cases them. So if `x` is a class

```
copy.deepcopy(x) is x
```

Is always `True`, thus you never actually make a copy.

As a side note, your class definition looks like it was written by a Java developer using Python for the first time. The Pythonic way to do it is [not to use getters and setters](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php&ved=0ahUKEwim2fDR4aLXAhVO22MKHa3-CCAQFggmMAA&usg=AOvVaw2mq0g1Fteb2EyK-VVQA7Ox) use properties, and *only when you need to*. Also, don't use double-underscores name-mangling unless you actually want that, which in this case, you dont.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer explains why your code doesn't work as you expect it to. Here's how you could rewrite your code in a more pythonic way.

```
class Student(object):
    def __init__(self, studentID, name):
        self.studentID = studentID
        self.name = name

students = []
name = input("Name: ")
students.append(Student(len(students), name))
name = input("Name: ")
students.append(Student(len(students), name))

for student in students:
    print(student.name)
```

You don't need to write getter and setter methods unless you have to do some special processing.